# rails g controller without unnecessary files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I just create a controller (manually by creating a file + "_controller.rb") in the controllers directory or does one have to run generate controller? I don't need the extra files but worried something might break later down the road if I do not use rails g

Answer (score 5):

You can use some generator flags to generate only the `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`. This can be handy to bypass helper and assets generation when you decide to do so.

```
rails g controller posts --skip-helper --skip-assets
```

Answer (score 4):

Thoughtbot have a [good article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/34229167067/reduce-application-clutter-disable-unwanted-rails) on this. If you want to continue using `rails g controller` for the convenience of also getting some test files do something like this in **application.rb**:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.helper false
  g.assets false
  # or 
  # g.stylesheets = false
  # g.javascripts = false
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a controller, no problems. If you need, you can create the views and the model (or anything else) in the future.

Just don't forget to add the routes in your routes file.